# in a Variant live m3u8 file, does .ts file have the same sequence number in different bitrate playlist with video content

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8

the question is:

- in different level playlist who have the same sequence number, MUST they present the same content(e.g. both level1-fileSequence2.ts, level2-fileSequence2.ts duration is 10:00:00-10:00:10) ?
- OR for thest different level's ts file, if they present the same period content, must they have the same sequence number?

playlist

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=150000,RESOLUTION=416x234, \
CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
level1.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=240000,RESOLUTION=416x234, \
CODECS="avc1.42e00a,mp4a.40.2"
level2.m3u8
```

level1.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10,
level1-fileSequence1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
level1-fileSequence2.ts
```

level2.m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2
#EXTINF:10,
level2-fileSequence2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
level2-fileSequence3.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, for both questions.

As a quick note, the name of the file doesn't matter at all. From the HLS specification:

> A client **MUST NOT** assume that segments with the same Media Sequence
> Number in different Variant Streams or Renditions have the same
> position in the presentation; Playlists **MAY** have independent Media
> Sequence Numbers.  Instead, a client **MUST** use the relative position
> of each segment on the Playlist timeline and its Discontinuity
> Sequence Number to locate corresponding segments.

Source: [HLS Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19#section-6.3.2)

Comment: what about VOD m3u8?

Comment: @look same as live

Comment: i have another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360804/how-to-synchronize-in-variant-live-m3u8-playlist-with-ext-x-discontinuity) here